# .gitignore is hidden in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

my VSCode (Insiders) hid the `.gitignore` a few days ago, and I cannot revert this, I tried searching a lot, but the solution of adding:

```json
{
...
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.gitignore": false
  },
...
}
```

in settings.json doesn't work, in the Settings with UI I only have:

- `.svn`
- `.hg`
- `CVS`
- `.DS_Store`
- `Thumbs.db`

The `.git` folder isn't hidden, nor `.vscode` or other files starting by `.`, just `.gitignore`.

I'm using VSCode Insiders `1.69.0-insider`, commit `4c72dedb4ad283a569f83a7389468c3ae2c742c3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because [`vscode/issue` 152891](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152891) has been fixed:

> set `"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": "true"`

Meaning `excludeGitIgnore` is now working in insider.

This is discussed in [issue 152543](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152543):

> Looks like a recent change means `.gitignore` now always gets hidden in Explorer unless you have set `"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true`, in which case the `.gitignore` file shows but none of the `.gitignored` files do.
>
> I saw that even having a folder without Git initialized in it still results in the `.gitignore` being hidden.
> Seems like it's a default behavior and the `explorer.excludeGitIgnore` setting changes this behavior.
>
> I tried messing with the `Files: Exclude` setting and adding a negated glob (or whatever that's officially called) to get the gitignore back, but that didn't work.

It should be fixed now.